# spring boot jpql like operation return equals operation

Tags: spring-boot, jpql, sql-like

I have this query

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Trx t WHERE ((:keyword IS NULL ) OR (:keyword IS NOT NULL AND (t.id like %:keyword%  OR t.account like %:keyword% )  ))" )
Page<Trx> findBy(@Param("keyword") String keyword, Pageable page);
```

For example `id value = 123456789`

If search `keyword= 123` result data not found
but if search with `keyword = 123456789` result data found
expected if search `keyword= 123` result the data found

Comment: You should provide more details about your setup and requirement. What are you looking for ?Are you looking for a Repository Method?

Comment: tq, i had updated the details

Comment: Enable SQL logging, and read/post the SQL query that is being generated.

Comment: the problem has solved , because the "id" for keyword is Integer , that can not using like query to select